# Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' fails on other computers

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I have a code that is splitting one workbook into just shy of 500. This code runs from one workbook and opens another to split. On my computer this works every time with no fail. On others the code will 1st stop at the ws.copy line. They stop the code and start again. The code will then work for the first 180-220 sheets then pop the 'SaveAs" error. I thought, based on online reading, that this was a memory problem or a timing error. To fix this, I added a .wait function to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Code below for reference.

```
Sub Splitbook()

Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Sheets("Steps").Range("C6")

Windows(MyFile).Activate

Dim xPath As String

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

ws.Copy

Name = ws.Range("C15").Value

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & Name & ".xlsx"

Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

newHour = Hour(Now())

newMinute = Minute(Now())

newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1

waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait waitTime

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox ("Split Complete. Press Ok to finish."), vbOKOnly, ("Thank you for your Patience.")

End Sub
```

***EDIT***

Based on your feedback I have updated the code as follows:

```
Sub Splitbook()

Dim MyFile As String

Dim wb As Workbook

MyFile = Sheets("Steps").Range("C6")

Set wb = Application.Workbooks(MyFile)

Windows(MyFile).Activate

Dim Loc As String

Loc = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In wb.Sheets

ws.Copy

Name = ws.Range("C15").Value

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Loc & "\" & Name & ".xlsx"

DoEvents

Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

MsgBox ("Split Complete. Press Ok to finish."), vbOKOnly, ("Thank you for your Patience.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Before the line `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False` add one more line `DoEvents` and now try it? BTW you can get rid of `Application.Wait waitTime`...

Comment: I added the 'DoEvents' but the code still failed. Thank you for the attempt.

Comment: A couple of things. 1) You should refrain from using proper commands as variable names, i.e. `Name`, 2) You should try stepping through your loop using `F8` with `ScreenUpdating` on and watch what happens (aside from your variable issue).  Using `ActiveWorkbook` causes problems, especially when creating new workbooks.  Using complete references or `ThisWorkbook` prevents you from applying changes to the wrong workbook.

Comment: Thank you for the information @DarrellH! I tried using `ThisWorkbook` but because i am running from a different workbook I get an error. I am still learning as much as I can so any help is valuable! When I walked through my code, everything works. I only get the error after about the 180ish file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus the dangers of `ActiveWorkbook`, `Activate`, `Select` and `ActiveSheet`.  They may not be what you expect and it matters where the code is located.  If you are running from a `Module`, `Sheet` or `ThisWorkbook` also makes a difference.  If you are going to run from a module, you will need to qualify the locations - which `Workbook`, `Sheet` or `Range` you are referencing.  When you create the new workbook by copying the sheet without a destination, that will be the active workbook for awhile, meanwhile you need to anchor to your starting file.

```
Sub Splitbook()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim OrigWb As Workbook
    Set OrigWb = ThisWorkbook 'or Set OrigWb = Workbooks("SplitFile") or some filename if not ThisWorkbook

    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = OrigWb.Path

    For Each ws In OrigWb.Sheets
        NewFileName = ws.Range("C15").Value
        ws.Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & NewFileName & ".xlsx"
            .Close False
        End With
        MsgBox ("Split Complete. Press Ok to finish."), vbOKOnly, ("Thank you for your Patience.")
    Next ws

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This works and will work unless `Range("C15")` is blank or invalid.  The file will not save and you will not know because you turned off alerts.  You may want to check that the range is not empty first.

`If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("C15").Value Then`

Comment: Thank you for this! This works a lot quicker than what I originally had. I am still running into the 1004 error on another computer. the `.SaveAs` line is still where the code fails. Any assistance on this?

Comment: You will run into a problem if the file has not been saved on that computer and there is no path, i.e. you opened from email no path has been created.  If this answer works, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Another option when transferring to another computer is to define the path in the code, like `FilePath = "C:\Users\ " &  Environ(Username) & "\Documents\"` using a path that people would have.

Comment: Both files (the one the code runs from and the file being split) are on network drives. So far it appears only one computer is having an issue running this. Would this be a limitation of the code or of that computer? I am marking answered because you did clear up issues with all but one! thank you for the assistance!

Comment: You can use the same type of code to specify a network drive.  A computer shouldn't be an issue unless their trust settings limit the use of macros or the user doesn't have access to the save location.  Another way to deal with the potential of invalid file names or access issues is to put in error handling, `On Error Goto BadfileName`, where you put in code to do something different if something goes wrong.  You can msgbox the filename or create a log and continue, etc.  That is a whole new topic though, but lot's of info available through this site or searches.